# Magento: Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object

Tags: magento

I get this error when I try to load my block in controller

Fatal error:  Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in ... on line ...

This is my config.xml

```
<blocks>
  <auction>
    <class>Custom_Auction_Block</class>
  </auction>
</blocks>
```

I call my block with this code in controller:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$autoupdate= $this->getLayout()->getBlock('auction.auto.update')->toHtml();
Mage::register('referrer_url', $this->_getRefererUrl());
$response['autoupdate'] = $autoupdate;
```

I create block in auction/block/product/autoupdate.php

```
class Custom_Auction_Block_Product_Autoupdate extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{
```

}

Here is my layout

```
<block type="auction/product_view" name="auction_view" template="auction/catalog/product/view.phtml">
        <block type="auction/product_autoupdate" name="auction.auto.update" as="auction_autoupdate" template="auction/catalog/product/autoupdate.phtml"/>
  </block>
```

I try to add "protected function _toHtml()" in my block too.. but it doesn't work.

Anyone can help me? FYI, I use magento 1.6.2.0
Thx in advance :)

Comment: does "auction/product_view" exist too? Also make sure that the layout.xml uses the correct layout update handles e.g. 'auction_product_view' see Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::addActionLayoutHandles()

Comment: yes, it is.. I extends it from Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View

Comment: its hard to help you on this, but try putting a die("asdf") in fornt of "class Custom_Auction_Block_Product_Autoupdate" to see if that file gets called at all

Comment: I get the respond, asdf is printed..

Comment: try `$autoupdate = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('auction/product_autoupdate')->setTemplate('auction/catalog/product/autoupdate.phtml')->toHtml();` and see if that works

Answer (score 2):

Your call to

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('auction.auto.update')
```

is not returning a block object.  That's either because Magento hasn't run your layout XML update for the particular page where you're running your code, or because it can't instantiate a block with the class alias `auction/product_autoupdate`.

My educated guess is the later, and your code and configuration samples are too imprecise to pinpoint a reason.  Try running the following code

```
$b = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('auction/product_autoupdate');
var_dump($b);
```

If `var_dump` doesn't dump an object, that means your configuration is incorrect.  Start tracing code in the `createBlock` method until you get to the point where it references the configuration to determine the block's PHP class. This should tell you what's wrong with your configuration.  Good luck.

Comment: I'm trying your code and it's give me many object >> object(Picodio_Auction_Block_Product_Autoupdate)#160 (29) {
  ["_viewDir":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["_viewVars":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }...

Comment: @may that means Magento can instantiate your block object, which means your config.xml and block setup is correct.  This also means the next most likely reason for your problem is your layout update XML code is in the wrong handle, or incorrectly configured.  Your code never gets called, so there's never a `auction.auto.update` block.